# cannot resolve the fromState attribute

Tags: apache-flex

What is the problems in this transition?? The error is Flex cannot resolve the fromState attribute.

```
<s:transitions>


    <s:Transition fromState="Viewer" toState="Editor">
        <s:Fade target="{viewerProductDetail}" duration="1000"/>
    </s:Transition>


    <s:Transition formState="Editor" toState="Viewer">
        <s:Fade target="{editorProductDetail}" duration="1000"/>
    </s:Transition>


</s:transitions>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second transition specifies "formState" not "fromState".  Are you sure you're reading the error correctly?